# Resolving Generics with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I'm having problems resolving generic interfaces/classes using Windsor Castle 2.5. I have the following classes and interfaces:

```cs
public interface IGenericDao<T> : IDao
public abstract class GenericDao<T> : IGenericDao<T> where T:class, new()
public class LocationDao : GenericDao<Location>, ILocationDao
```

For the registration I am using the following lines of code

```cs
c.Register(
           Component.For(typeof(IGenericDao<>))
               .ImplementedBy(typeof(GenericDao<>)));

c.Register(Component.For<ILocationDao>().ImplementedBy<LocationDao>());
```

Now, when I'm trying to resolve `ILocationDao`

```cs
var i = c.Resolve<ILocationDao>();
```

the return value is a `Castle.Proxies.ILocationDaoProxy` and I'm not able to cast it to a `LocationDao`.

When I remove `GenericDao<Location>` from class `LocationDao'

```cs
public class LocationDao : ILocationDao
```

everything works fine. So I guess that I'm doing something wrong with the registration.

Could you please help me?

Comment: @weston This is the implementation of [GenericDao.cs](http://pastebin.com/ZTnCfaMM) and here is its implementation [LocationDao.cs](http://pastebin.com/BcsC1ePR).

Comment: @weston, if `LocationDao` wouldn't implement all `abstract` methods, it would fail to compile.

Comment: @svick Yes sorry you are right, ignore my comment Christian

Answer (score 2):

If you're telling the container that you want `ILocationDao`, you shouldn't cast the result to `LocationDao`, just use it as `ILocationDao`.

If you are sure using the interface is not enough for you, then register `LocationDao` as `LocationDao` and resolve that.